# How to find the inverse function of $f: \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, inverse

How to find the inverse function of $f: \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$?

for example, $u= x+2y, v=xe^y$, how to find the inverse?

Comment: The inverse is not an elementary function. You need something like Lambert's W-function to express it.

Comment: is it possible to finding an inverse function for $f(x,y)=(x+2y,xe^y)$ under certain condition?

Comment: @J.Johnny1905 What sort of conditions do you mean?

Comment: Here's the original question about the inverse function theorem:  (a)Where is the (u; v) coordinate system nonsingular? In other words, at what points does
the inverse function theorem tell us that the map F(x; y) = (u; v) has a local inverse, so
that (u; v) can be used as coordinates?(b)At the point (x; y) = (5; 0), compute the value of ay/au(partial derivative).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What I thought and what i did is that I calculated the Jacobian for the coordinate of this function. And I noticed that when X =2, the coordinate system is singular. But then I looked at 2nd question, I have no idea how to get partial Y over partial u without finding the inverse of $f(x,y)=(u,v)$

Comment: @J.Johnny1905 just to add an one-dimensional example of the general advice at start of Lord Farin's nice answer. The basic method is same as one-dimensional case. To find inverse function of $f(x)=y$ just solve for $x$ and recognize $x=f^{-1}(y)$. For example, $f(x)=1+1/x=y$ then solve for $x = 1/(y-1) = f^{-1}(y)$. But, as you've been warned, it may not be possible to actually do the algebra.

Answer (score 2):

A general advice would be to try and express one of $x$ and $y$ by manipulating $u$ and $v$. It is hard to be more specific, because the niceness of $f$ (e.g. its being expressible in terms of elementary functions) does not generally imply niceness of $f^{-1}$.

For example, in the present case, we can isolate an expression in terms of $x$ by eliminating the $e^y$ part of $v$:

$$v\,\exp \left(-\frac u2\right) = x\exp y\exp\left(-\frac x2-y\right) = x \exp\left(-\frac x2\right)$$

From here on, we find that, using the [Lambert W-function](http://enwp.org/Lambert_W_function):

\begin{align}
v \exp\left(-\frac u2\right) &= x \exp\left(-\frac x2\right)\\
-\frac v2\exp\left(-\frac u2\right) &= -\frac x2 \exp\left(-\frac x2\right)\\
W\left(-\frac v2\exp\left(-\frac u2\right)\right) &= -\frac x2\\
-2 W\left(-\frac v2\exp\left(-\frac u2\right)\right) &= x
\end{align}

and using this expression for $x$, we can use $y = \frac12(u-x)$ to find $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.